# ASP.NET API Unit Tests not running: Could not load file or assembly... tests.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have a new ASP.NET Web API with Unit Tests using the default template on Visual Studio 2015 (image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ici4S.png)).

The project comes with a Values controller and a ValuesControllerTest. It turns out the test don't execute. They don't fail either nor throw any errors. Only hint is a message on the Output window:

```
 ------ Discover test started ------ Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\Mac\Home\Documents\Visual Studio
2015\Projects\TravelGood\TravelGood.Tests\bin\Debug\TravelGood.Tests.dll'
or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.697) ==========
```

I run the tests by right clicking on the valuesControllerTest.cs file -> Run Tests

Do you know what should I do to get the tests to run?
[image]